# Contain sphere script into in Class

Tags: python, class, matplotlib, 3d

I'm trying to contain this script in a Class.  This is in order to learn how classes work and to make the functions usable elsewhere.

This script makes a sphere in 3D matplotlib.  The equation of a sphere is x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = r^2.  If we add coeffecients to any of the variables, it elongates or shortens the sphere into an ellipse.  I'd like to be able to call this class and change the r(radius) value and maybe some coefficients.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# CREATE EMPTY LISTS
xs = []
ys = []
zs = []

# FOR EACH Z PLANE "z=dd", 
# CREATE CIRCLE WITH RADIUS ppp "ppp=100-dd^2"
def generateZ(dd):
    ppp = 100 - dd**2
    for xxx in range(-10,10):
        zs.append(dd)
        xs.append(xxx)
        yyy = np.sqrt(ppp - xxx**2)
        ys.append(yyy)
    for xxx in range(-10,10):
        zs.append(dd)
        xs.append(xxx)
        yyy = -np.sqrt(ppp - xxx**2)
        ys.append(yyy)

# GENERATE X AND Y'S FOR EACH Z
for dd in range(-10,10):
    generateZ(dd)

# SCATTER X,Y, AND Z COORDINATES
ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs)

# LABEL AXES
ax.set_xlabel("x axis")
ax.set_ylabel("y axis")
ax.set_zlabel("z axis")

# SET DIMENSIONS OF GRAPH
ax.set_ylim([-12,12])
ax.set_xlim([12,-12])
ax.set_zlim([-12,12])
# SHOW GRAPH
plt.show()
```

I've tried simply just adding class container and calling it.  The result is that self isn't defined...

Here is the attempt.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

class Sphere(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.xs = []
        self.ys = []
        self.zs = []

    # CREATE EMPTY LISTS


    # FOR EACH Z PLANE "z=dd", 
    # CREATE CIRCLE WITH RADIUS ppp "ppp=100-dd^2"
    def generateZ(self, dd):
        self.ppp = 100 - dd**2
        for xxx in range(-10,10):
            self.zs.append(dd)
            self.xs.append(xxx)
            self.yyy = np.sqrt(ppp - xxx**2)
            self.ys.append(yyy)
        for xxx in range(-10,10):
            self.zs.append(dd)
            self.xs.append(xxx)
            self.yyy = -np.sqrt(ppp - xxx**2)
            self.ys.append(yyy)

    # GENERATE X AND Y'S FOR EACH Z
    for dd in range(-10,10):
        self.generateZ(dd)

    # SCATTER X,Y, AND Z COORDINATES
    self.ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs)

    # LABEL AXES
    self.ax.set_xlabel("x axis")
    self.ax.set_ylabel("y axis")
    self.ax.set_zlabel("z axis")

    # SET DIMENSIONS OF GRAPH
    self.ax.set_ylim([-12,12])
    self.ax.set_xlim([12,-12])
    self.ax.set_zlim([-12,12])

    # SHOW GRAPH
    self.plt.show()

john = Sphere.generateZ(10)
```

Comment: Faaaaantastic. Now I don't see any class here, and what's your question exactly?

Comment: Excuse me.  Just edited.  Any help appreciated.  Not versed in using classes.

Comment: You should read about classes, `__init__` functions etc...

Answer (score 1):

When using classes or functions, it is of utmost importance to keep the indentation consistent. In the example code, indentation is wrong.

If we correct for that the remaining problem is that the class is not initialized. To explain that we don't need matplotlib or any complex code. 
Consider the following class.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

    @staticmethod    
    def mystaticmethod(arg):
        print(arg)

    def mymethod(self, arg):
        print(arg)
        print(self.arg)
```

It has an `__init__` method and two further methods. One is a static method, the other is a normal method. Since the static method does not rely on the class being instantiated, you may call it like

```
Foo.mystaticmethod(3)
```

However if you try the same with `mymethod`,

```
Foo.mymethod(3)
```

it will fail, because the class has not been instatiated, i.e. there is no instance of `Foo` which would be `self`. In order to use this method, you first need an instance of the class.

```
Foo(4).mymethod(3)
```

I will leave it to you to translate this concept to your class.